# Facebook OG image set as undefined, using NextJs

Tags: facebook, next.js, metadata, facebook-opengraph

I have a website where I dinamically set the og:image, using Next.js
The thing here is that everything display the og:image correctly (Tests bellow) but not Facebook, I just keep getting this error:

[image: Facebook undefined image]

The weird part is that other pages (Like Twitter) does display the right image, and I checked the source code in the explorer and indeed, the image is there:

[image: metadata]

Here are some things I tried, all of them display the right thumbnail:

1. Testing on Chrome on localhost/online with Social Share Preview Extention and Open Graph Checker
2. Checking the URL of the image
3. Hardcoding the URL of the image

Here's the code of that section:

```
export default function PageHead({
                                   title,
                                   pageURL,
                                   metaPageDescription,
                                   metaImage,
                                 }) {


  const pageTitle = title || 'Title';
  const pageDescription = metaPageDescription || 'Description';
  const prodUrl = pageURL || '<Right url>';
  const prodImage = `https://diamondstandard.co/${metaImage}` || '<Right url>';

  return (
    <Head>
      <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' />

      <meta property='og:type' content='website' />
      <meta property='og:url' content={prodUrl} />
      <meta property='og:title' content={pageTitle} />

      <meta name='description' content={pageDescription} />
      <meta property='og:description' content={pageDescription} />
      <meta property='og:image' content={prodImage} />
      <meta property='og:image:type' content='image/jpg' />
      <meta property='og:image:width' content='1080' />
      <meta property='og:image:height' content='608' />

      <title>{pageTitle}</title>

      {/* Twitter */}
      <meta name='twitter:card' content='summary' key='twcard' />
      <meta name='twitter:url' content={prodUrl} />
      <meta name='twitter:title' content={pageTitle} />
      <meta name='twitter:image' content={prodImage} />

  
    </Head>
  );
```

Comment: You removed the URL which makes it impossible to explain what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @WizKid Looks like the base URL is visible in the code snippet.

Comment: @WizKid Indeed I didn't want to show the URL but I forgot to remove it from the code snippet, anyway the URL is this 
https://diamondstandard.co/images/thumbnails/technology-thumbnail.png

Comment: That is a URL to an image. An image of course doesn't have any OG-tags because that you put in your HTML code. So what is the URL to something that returns HTML?

Comment: @WizKid, the metatag needs an url  
    <meta property='og:image' content='https://diamondstandard.co/images/thumbnails/technology-thumbnail.png' />

Comment: What is the URL to the page that contains the og-tags?

Comment: there are plenty, here's the one with the metadata I just shared:

https://diamondstandard.co/technology

Also, for some reason, a test stage enviroment does display the thumbnails, it may be the configuration on the prod enviroment

Comment: It seems like the canonical URL is redirecting the og image url, and hence find it as undefined